# Unexpected delay in API response time on Node server

Tags: node.js, npm, https, axios, request

I am working on a chat bot which uses node as its backend server. So, to respond back to user's query, I have to make some other api call which are taking long to respond which causes delay in providing response to the user.

My problem is whenever i call a third-party api from node server it's response time is around 500-900ms whereas Postman gives back the same response in 80-120ms.

I have tried using following modules, but all of them give almost same response time:

- request
- axios
- https

How to achieve the same response time which i am getting in the Postman?

Comment: postman, from the same server the node server is on?

Comment: Diagnose the request with curl option [--trace](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace) on your server. It will help you debug whether the problem is on the route or on your server.

Comment: @KevinB No, on postman i am calling that third-party api directly.

Comment: @DipanshuKumarSuman not exactly what i meant. when making a request, the route from client to server can impact how long it takes to receive a response. If you run postman on your local machine, and node is on a cloud server located in another country or even another part of the world, you can reasonably expect the response times to differ.

Comment: @KevinB I am currently doing all the tests from my local server. Only thing hosted here is that third-party api. Just to be clear, Both Node server and Postman are running on my machine. So if there is any latency due to region difference, it should be reflected almost same in both the places.

Comment: @PetrHejda I checked it with cURL --trace option too. Response time is simiar to what i am getting from Postman

Comment: @KevinB Just to be sure that there is not any issue with my bot logic implementation, i created a simple node app which only call that api. But the result is same.